# Finding number of occurences in another table including null

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a few tables in my powerbi model and i have a simple problem that i cannot bring myself to comprehend.

I have

- a first table with a thorough listing of all the trains that have run this year (Key = date + train_number)
- a second table which is a listing of all the occurences of a particular event (a Passenger Announcement made on the speakers). All of them are linked to a date + train_number)

I have a by directional 1 to many relationship between these two tables based on this same key

i'd like to retrieve the number of events that occured on a given train of a given day, and i can't seem to find how do do this... (i know it's stupid).

I would've like to have a simple column in table 1 that retrieves to total number of events, but a calculate(count(events), table1[key] = table2[key]) is invalid. I have tried creating a measure that count the number of occurences, this seems to gove good results, but i don't seem to retrieve the train with no data in table 2 (i expected the measure to return 0)

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can go by the following, add thee column to table1:

```
EventCount = 
    var key = table1[Key]
    return CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(table2), Filter(table2, key = table2[Key]))
```